# Battery holder for protected 18650 battery

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion

When placing a 18650 Li-Ion rechargeable battery in its battery holder, everything is fine. The problem is with **protected** 18650 Li-Ion battery. There are protection circuits attached into them and they are longer in size. Hardly can they go into the battery holder or come out and in most of case they are damaged.

What battery holders should I use for protected 18650 Li-Ion rechargeable batteries?

Comment: Did you try measuring the new length and getting the appropriate holder?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I have to order new batteries to measure their length. Unfortunately, I don't have them with myself at the moment. That was from my previous experiment.

Comment: 18650 is actually a measurement of the size of the battery - 18mm x 65mm. If your battery with protection circuits included isn't the right size, find a better battery!

Comment: Have you looked at those [PCB mount holders by Keystone](http://www.conrad.com/ce/en/product/651325/Keystone----Single-contact-for-18650-cells-16-19-mm-------L-x-W-x-H-13-x-15-x-1964-mm)? If you can design the board that will hold the cells, you can make the holder in any length you want. I usually use the AA version of those for NiMH cells. They also have very low resistance as a bonus.

Answer (score 2):

This is the normal situation, the 65mm is the internal length of the cell and the protection circuitry adds to it. If it was 65mm I'd worry about the protection circuitry not being there.

Buy a holder that can handle a ~67mm or ~69mm cell (depending if the button is there or not).

**Do not** measure the battery length as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Unless using a plastic caliper.

Comment: Or put a piece of tape on one jaw, a few thousandths on this measurement won't hurt.

Comment: @MattYoung The tape I used measures 0.04mm (about 0.0015").

Comment: The masking tape on my bench measured 0.002" with my old school analog calipers.

Comment: Mine was "invisible" tape (from Staples). Maybe 1 thou of tape and 0.5 thou of adhesive.

Comment: Jeeze.  I make a joke because I happen to own a pair of plastic calipers that are barely better than a ruler, and look what happens.

Comment: if 65 is including the protection circuit, why it is very hard to push the batteries into the battery holder?

Comment: @zahmati it's ~69mm including the protection circuit (see caliper)- it adds an extra 3mm which causes it to not fit nicely